# Select all text inside TextField when it gets focus

Tags: flutter, dart

On `TextField` foucus I want to select all text so that when the user starts typing the existing text gets deleted.

This will be alternative of : `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` in Android.

How to achive this?

Answer (score 66):

It's also possible to set the selection in `onTap` event. Like this:

```
TextField(
    controller: _controller,
    onTap: () => _controller.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: 0, extentOffset: _controller.value.text.length),
)
```

Comment: Nice one! No need to declare a `FocusNode()`.

Comment: very accurate solution!

Answer (score 50):

Pass a controller and focusNode explicitly, then you have full control:

```
final _controller = TextEditingController(); 
final _focusNode = FocusNode();

initState() {
  super.initState();
  _focusNode.addListener(() {
    if(_focusNode.hasFocus) {
      _controller.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: 0, extentOffset: _controller.text.length);
    }
  });
}

build() => TextField(controller: _controller, focusNode: _focusNode);
```

**Update**
from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28307#issuecomment-467952074 to prevent endless loop:

```
_controller.addListener(() {
  final newText = _controller.text.toLowerCase();
  _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(
    text: newText,
    selection: TextSelection(baseOffset: newText.length, extentOffset: newText.length),
    composing: TextRange.empty,
  );
});
```

Comment: Dart 2:

_controller.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: 0, extentOffset: _controller.value.text.length);

Comment: If I want to select the text from simple Text Widget. How can I pass the controller to select the text,

Comment: @rishabhsingh sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: `Text(
                      "Hello This is My Flutter Code ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 23,
                          wordSpacing: 4.0,
                          letterSpacing: 2.0),
                    ),`     I want to select the flutter on long press, How I can implement this?   @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: That update is unclear. Is it instead of the original code? Does it go after the original code? Nothing works, nothing ever works.

Comment: @TimSim sorry, I got confused myself. Add `_controller.addListener(...)` after the line `super.initState()`

Comment: i know its late but, how to select teh text if i dont have a controller. I have a listview where there is a textfield. since its a listview i cant use texteditingcontroller or else 1 single change in one field changes in all other fields. thus i am forced to use initial value. Is it possible to select the text without controller?

Comment: @Trend74X I think you need one TextEditingController per item in the list.

Answer (score 19):

It's actually much easier than the accepted answer.

First initialize a TextEditingController.

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();
```

Then, somewhere within your build method (probably within your edit text logic), set the text and the selection props like so.

```
_controller.text = textValue;
_controller.selection = TextSelection(
    baseOffset: 0,
    extentOffset: textValue.length,
);
```

In the TextFormField, make sure to assign the controller and set autofocus to true.

```
TextFormField(
    controller: _controller,
    autofocus: true,
    //...more properties
```

That's it!

Comment: This is working well ! 
One question though : the selection menu does not show on tap. It still needs a long tap to show. Any idea how I could show it as well ?

Answer (score 14):

For a cleaner, reusable experience an [Extension class method](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) (see note below) is handy.

```
extension TextEditingControllerExt on TextEditingController {
  void selectAll() {
    if (text.isEmpty) return;
    selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: 0, extentOffset: text.length);
  }
}
```

On the field:

```
TextField(
  controller: myController,
  onTap: myController.selectAll
)
```

#### Example

On Dartpad:
https://dartpad.dev/?id=271737b109637f90a2fe5ea55ea2ac43

#### Note

In `extension` classes, `this` can be omitted.

`text` is assumed to be: `this.text` i.e. `<this instance of controller>.text`

Same with `selection` being actually `this.selection`.

Comment: Tried this and is very buggy, sometimes not showing the cursor when selecting, and other times placing cursor at beginning of text

Comment: @Kevin have reproduction example showing buggy behavior?

Comment: Agree with kevin, this looks like it should work programmatically, but it does not select all. (Neither do any of the other selection suggestions!)

Answer (score 9):

As of Dart 2:

```
 controller1.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset:0, extentOffset:controller1.text.length);
```

Comment: for me this is putting the cursor at the end of the textformfield, but it isn't selecting (highlighting) all the text.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I believe it should be `controller1.value.text.length` per @d____ 's answer